# Using @ConfigurationProperties for partitional different prefix

Tags: java, spring, configurationproperties

I have my application.yaml, f.e:

```yaml
bookshop:
  properties:
    books:
      maxSize:
        title: 60
        description: 800
      price:
        commonDiscount: 10
      sale: true
```

Now I create 'getter-class' for getting this values with `@Value` annotation:

```java
@Getter
@Component
public class BookSettingsGetter {

  @Value("${bookshop.properties.books.maxSize.title}")
  private Integer titleMaxSize;
  @Value("${bookshop.properties.books.maxSize.description}")
  private Integer descriptionMaxSize;
  @Value("${bookshop.properties.books.price.commonDiscount}")
  private Integer commonDiscountPercent;
  @Value("${bookshop.properties.books.sale}")
  private Boolean allowSaleBooks;
}
```

But I want to make it with `@ConfigurationProperties`. A common part of all values is `bookshop.properties.books` and I can get easy only `bookshop.properties.books.sale`.
How to get other properties with `@ConfigurationProperties` in one class? It's possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you need to show the attempt you made that isn't working as you want.